# Coffeescript `in` operator doesn't work with 2D array

Tags: coffeescript

Checking for values in 1D arrays works..

```
coffee> 1 in [1,2]
true
```

But:

```
coffee> [1, 1] in [[1, 1], [1, 2]]
false
```

Checking for values in 2D arrays doesn't.

Am I missing something, is this a bug or is this intended?

Comment: @Bergi whoa TIL. Is there any neat way to do this in coffeescript?

Comment: Also, there aren't any 2D arrays in (Coffee|Java)Script, that's just an array whose elements happen to be other arrays. AFAIK, there's nothing fancy in CoffeeScript for comparing arrays element by element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Javascript does not count two "equal" arrays as equal

```
[1,1] === [1,1]
--> false
[1,1] == [1,1]
--> false
```

So it would be counterintuitive for coffeescript to do what you're proposing.

You could write your own method to do the comparison, or you could use something like Lodash's `isEqual()` method https://lodash.com/docs#isEqual